# How to understand the sentence,"Both were wonderful hackers, but they could otherwise have hardly been more different. "?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Is this usage,["could have hardly been more different
"](https://www.filfre.net/2012/05/the-ibm-pc-part-2/), standard and easy to understand for native English speaker?
After reading the blog, Kildall and Gates are probably very different, but Google translate means they are the same except "wonderful hackers".

Comment: How can two answers get two upvotes with no explanation at all?

Answer (score 4):

It's understandable, but the word order seems strange to me.
I think it would be better like this:
"Both were wonderful hackers, but otherwise, they could hardly have been more different."

Comment: My thoughts exactly  The "otherwise" is awkwardly placed and interrupts the flow of the thought. Not saying it's wrong, just needs tweaking to make it clearer.

Comment: It's the placing of "hardly" which jangled for me. Natural only _before_ "have".

Comment: Is there a rule for the position of "hardly"  or anywhere ok?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's easily understood by native English speakers.
I means that there was one thing, hacking, that both Kildall and Gates did very well, but otherwise the two men were very different.

Comment: You often hear something like 'Both were wonderful hackers, but **apart from that**, they could have hardly been more different.'

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is grammatically correct, and it effectively conveys the idea that the two individuals are skilled hackers but possess many differences in other aspects.

Answer (score -3):

to hardly be  more x
to hardly be less x
to hardly be as x as y

examples with other verbs:
**can** hardly be more different
**can have hardly been** more different
**may** hardly be more different
**should have hardly been** more different

hardly is the same as scarcely here.

> Hardly ever, rarely, scarcely, seldom
> Hardly ever, rarely, scarcely
> and seldom are frequency adverbs. We can use them to refer to things
> that almost never happen, or do not happen very often. They have a
> negative meaning. We use them without not. Rarely, scarcely and seldom
> are more common in writing than in speaking:
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hardly)

otherwise is often used comparatively:
These tables are black, brown or white. Otherwise, their shape and size is exactly the same.

otherwise= in all other respects

Comment: Disregard the downvoters, please/